# Find odd and even digits for credit card validation

Tags: python, string, slice

I took a CS50 course, and this is my first time using Python. I'm working on problem set 6 - credit card. This is my code:

```
from cs50 import get_string
from itertools import chain
import re

def main():
    # get credit card number from user
    credit_card = get_string("Number: ")

    # take odd and even number from Credit Card and then store it in reversed
    # 4003600000000014 || even = 10000604 || count from last-to-second

    even =''.join(reversed (re.findall("\w",credit_card[::2])))
    odd =''.join(reversed (re.findall("\w",credit_card[1::2])))

    # convert strings to integer
    even = [int(i) for i in even]
    odd = [int(i) for i in odd]

    
    # add each number in the list
    # BUT for SUM_EVEN number, multiply each digit by 2. and there will be the case the result is greater than 9
    # ex : 6 * 2 = 12 || so we need to seperate it (12 = 1 + 2)
    
    sum_even = sum([int(((2 * x) % 10) + ((2 * x)) / 10) for x in even])
    sum_odd = sum(odd)
    checksum = sum_even + sum_odd
    

    # FIND first digit and first two digit
    first_digit = int(credit_card[0:1])
    first_two_digit = int(credit_card[0:2])
    

    # VALIDATE the credit card and check which company by its structure
    if checksum % 10 == 0:
        if first_digit == 4 and (len(credit_card) == 13 or len(credit_card) == 16):
            print("VISA")
        elif (first_two_digit == 34 or first_two_digit == 37) and len(credit_card) == 15:
            print("AMEX")
        elif (first_two_digit >= 51 and first_two_digit <= 55) and len(credit_card) == 16:
            print("MASTERCARD")
        else:
            print("INVALID")
    else:
        print("INVALID")


main()
```

**4**0**0**3**6**0**0**0**0**0**0**0**0**0**1**4

So, we need to get second-to-last digit (or we can call it EVEN number) on the credit card and then multiply each digit by 2. Then we sum with the ODD number.

The thing is, my code is almost successful. It successfully prints VISA and MASTERCARD credit card. But for AMEX, it's always INVALID. Later I found out that AMEX credit card uses 15-digit numbers. MASTERCARD uses 16-digit numbers. VISA uses 13 or 16 digit numbers.

For ODD digit (13 or 15), my code didn't take ODD and EVEN number in the same way as EVEN digit (16).

```
for example: 

VISA : 4003600000000014
even: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 4]
odd: [4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0]

but for AMEX: 378282246310005
even: [5, 0, 1, 6, 2, 8, 8, 3]
odd: [0, 0, 3, 4, 2, 2, 7]
```

Can you see? AMEX 'even' didn't start from second-to-last digit like VISA did. In fact, even and odd are swapped.

So, I know there's a mistake with this code that i found myself:

```
even =''.join(reversed (re.findall("\w",credit_card[::2])))
odd =''.join(reversed (re.findall("\w",credit_card[1::2])))
```

Is there something that I need to change with the code to handle whether the digit is 13, 15, or 16. Or perhaps, my code is wrong, and I need to use another code to find EVEN and ODD number on credit card.

Comment: The `re.findall()` invocation seems unnecessary (assuming the `credit_card` variable only contains numbers). Simply `even = credit_card[::2]` will give you the even-positioned digits, and `odd = credit_card[1::2]` gives you the odd-positioned digits.

Comment: It's still INVALID for and only AMEX :(
I think something wrong with the substring. It didn't treat credit card with odd (15, 13) digit in a good way.

Comment: Is the original problem statement available somewhere? It's a little hard to tell what your program should be doing.

Comment: This is full explanation, but for C: https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/1/credit/  --- and this is for Python. Which is no explanation: https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/6/credit/

Comment: @Kevinkun Can you confirm my answer solves your problem? It seems to work okay for me when I try it with your code.

Comment: @ekhumoro I just do exactly like your solution. It works well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem states that you must *take every other digit, starting with the second-to-last digit*. But as you've discovered, this is not the same as simply taking the odd and even digits of the number, since it will give different results for numbers with odd or even lengths. The solution is to reverse the number *first*, and then take its odd and even digits:

```
# reverse the digits
cc_reversed = credit_card[::-1]
print(cc_reversed)

# convert to integers
even = [int(i) for i in cc_reversed[1::2]]
odd = [int(i) for i in cc_reversed[::2]]
print(even)
print(odd)
```

For 4003600000000014 (VISA), this prints:

```
4100000000063004
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 4]
[4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0]
```

and for 378282246310005 (AMEX), it prints:

```
500013642282873
[0, 0, 3, 4, 2, 2, 7]
[5, 0, 1, 6, 2, 8, 8, 3]
```

So now the list of even digits will always start with the penultimate digit of the original number (i.e. `1` for VISA and `0` for AMEX in the above examples).

**UPDATE**:

To clarify, here's a simpler example:

```
>>> '0010'[::2] # even digits
'01'
>>> '0010'[::2][::-1] # even digits, reversed
'10'
```

For even-length numbers, taking the even digits will always end on the second to last digit (which is what we want). But this will never work for odd-length numbers, because that will always end on the *last digit*:

```
>>> '00010'[::2] # even digits
'000'
```

What we need to do instead is take every other digit *starting from the second to last digit*. This can be guaranteed by reversing the number first:

```
>>> '0010'[::-1] # reversed
'0100'
>>> '0010'[::-1][1::2] # reversed, every other digit
'10'
>>> '00010'[::-1] # reversed
'01000'
>>> '00010'[::-1][1::2] # reversed, every other digit
'10'
```

It's actually misleading to talk about odd and even digits. What really matters is making sure you always *start from the same place*.